# How to pre deploy the instances used by sagemaker for training?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker takes ~3 mins for `preparing the instances for training` and around ~1 min for the actual training and artifact publishing.

I want to pre-deploy some ec2 instances which it can use for training. However I couldn't find an option to specify pre deployed instances in the `ResourceConfig` part of the `createTrainingJob`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, As the EC2 instances use for training must be managed by SageMaker.
The closest thing is [SageMaker Local](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/use-the-amazon-sagemaker-local-mode-to-train-on-your-notebook-instance/), and it requires triggering the job from within the EC2 instances you provisioned.